# Удалить файл через команду ssh без введения пароля

Tags: ssh, vagrant

`ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p23 "rm -rf /path/.../file.php`

Собственно, хотел выполнить эту команду, чтобы не было запрашивания пароля.
Подскажите как правильно вставить в эту команду пароль.

Comment: SSH-ключи . . .

Comment: Через ключи - можно, встречал в версии для Windows параметр -pw, но в linux такого нет.

Comment: Нет, хотелось не через ключ, а дать какую-то команду и вставить в нее известный мне пароль.

Comment: Да, мне нужен linux ubuntu

Comment: "sshpass -p 'password' rsync -ratlz -avz -e 'port' pathFrom pathTo"
У меня есть похожая команда, у неё все работает, вот только она высылает файлы с localhost на remote server, а тут мне нужно с того remote server`a удалить file.php например.